# Find unique value in group of groups

Tags: c#, linq

Guess i have two groups

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    internal class Student
    {
        public string Name;
        public string Surname;
        public int Mark;
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var twoGroups = new List<List<Student>>
            {
                new List<Student>
                {
                    new Student { Name = "Anna",  Surname = "Mors",  Mark = 4 }, 
                    new Student { Name = "Jimmy", Surname = "Lemon", Mark = 4 }
                },
                new List<Student>
                {
                    new Student { Name = "Anna",  Surname = "Mors",   Mark = 4 }, 
                    new Student { Name = "Tommy", Surname = "Wojski", Mark = 4 },
                    new Student { Name = "Jimmy", Surname = "Lemon",  Mark = 4 }
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

How can i get unique persons from both groups (by Name or any other property) with linq?

It's obvious there is Tommy, but i dont know how can i pick him with linq (or pick a list of unique persons.

***UPD***

Also, can i pick group contain only unique student.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    internal class GroupOfStudents
    {
        public string Code;
        public List<Student> Students;
    }

    internal class Student
    {
        public string Name;
        public string Surname;
        public int Mark;
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var twoGroups = new List<GroupOfStudents>
            {
                new GroupOfStudents
                {
                    Code = "A1",
                    Students = new List<Student>
                    {
                        new Student { Name = "Anna",  Surname = "Mors",  Mark = 4 }, 
                        new Student { Name = "Jimmy", Surname = "Lemon", Mark = 4 }
                    }
                },
                new GroupOfStudents()
                {
                    Code = "B2",
                    Students = new List<Student>
                    {
                        new Student { Name = "Anna",  Surname = "Mors",   Mark = 4 }, 
                        new Student { Name = "Tommy", Surname = "Wojski", Mark = 4 },
                        new Student { Name = "Jimmy", Surname = "Lemon",  Mark = 4 }
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

I think i need to pick student and push him to new Group with same name, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SelectMany`, `GroupBy` and `Count`

```
IEnumerable<Student> uniqueStudents = twoGroups 
    .SelectMany(list => list)
    .GroupBy(student => student.Name)
    .Where(g => g.Count() == 1)
    .Select(g => g.First());
```

This selects only students which aren't contained multiple times in one of both(or both) lists.

If you want to group-by multiple properties use an anonymous type

```
    .GroupBy(student => new { student.Name, student.Surname })
```

If you want to allow duplicates in the same list but not across multiple lists:

```
IEnumerable<Student> uniqueStudents = twoGroups 
    .SelectMany((list, index) => list.Select(student => new { student, index }))
    .GroupBy(x => x.student.Name)
    .Where(g =>
    {
        int index = g.First().index;
        return g.Skip(1).All(x => x.index == index);
    })
    .Select(g => g.First().student);
```

---

Acc. your **Edit**

If you want to remove all students from the lists which appear also in other groups:

```
var studentNameLookup = twoGroups.SelectMany(g => g.Students).ToLookup(s => s.Name);
twoGroups.ForEach(g => g.Students.RemoveAll(s => studentNameLookup[s.Name].Count() > 1));
```

Comment: Oh, i updated my questinon, so if possible, answer for this please, i this i will mark yours as answer.

Comment: Oh i meant that first group contain student with same name as second group. So we pop this student from both group. Third student contain in second group too (by name), so we pop him from all groups too. Like this, i am not even sure we could make it with linq.

Comment: Only in 2 or n groups, not in every group.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145986/discussion-between-ionmike-and-tim-schmelter).

Answer (score 3):

1. flaten the nested lists into one `SelectMany()`
2. group by unique criterias `GroupBy()` (I choose all properties)
3. select unique records `Where()`

code:

```
List<Student> result = twoGroups.SelectMany(x => x)
                       .GroupBy(x => new { x.Name, x.Surname, x.Mark })
                       .Where(x => x.Count() == 1)
                       .Select(x => x.First())
                       .ToList();
```